# Can I use Sharepoint as a webhost for a HTML project

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, html, hosting

I have a HTML project with lots of folders and files (.js,.html,.css,.png) and I was wondering if it would be easy to use Sharepoint as a webhost, without having to change the extensions to .aspx.

I'am not very experienced with Sharepoint. I usually use an Apache webserver for this purpose.

Does anyone has experience with this?

Comment: SharePoint draait bovenop een IIS server, dus vraag systeembeheer of je daarvan gebruik mag maken.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to use SharePoint in this situation !, but if your goal is to show a page within your SharePoint Page, So you can use the `Page Viewer Web Part` to display a Web page, file, or folder on a SharePoint page.

In this case, you just need to

- Create the default SharePoint pages then
- Add the Page viewer web part and
- Provide the URL of your page that you need to host within SharePoint.

To know how to use `Page Viewer web part` check [Display a Web page on a SharePoint page by adding the Page Viewer Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-a-Web-page-on-a-SharePoint-page-by-adding-the-Page-Viewer-Web-Part-7f61feec-9b3d-4805-a960-07636ba59527)